# Getting used constants in a class with reflection

Tags: c#, string, constants, system.reflection

So... please take a look at this example:

```
public class StatesList() {
    public const string State1Name = "State1";
    public const string State2Name = "State2";
    public const string State3Name = "State3";
}

public class Test() {

    private currentState = StatesList.State1Name;

    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        while(true) {
            if(currentState == StatesList.State1Name) {
                State1();
            } else if (currentState == StatesList.State3Name) {
                State2();
            }
        }
    }

    public void ChangeState(string newState) {
       currentState = newState;
    }

    public void State1() {
       // do stuff.
       if(iAmSilly) {
           ChangeState(StatesList.State3Name);
       }
    }

    public void State2() {
       // do stuff.
       if(!iAmSilly) {
           ChangeState(StatesList.State1Name);
       }
    }
}
```

What I would like to achieve is to be able to "parse" the Test class and create a list with the used state names. In the example, I would like to be able to create a list containing StatesList.State1Name and StatesList.State3Name. Is it possible to do with reflection or do I actually have to create a parser (loading the cs file as a text) to achieve it?

Thank you very much  :-)

Comment: _Why_ do you need to know which are used?  What's the end goal?  There may be a different way to solve your problem.

Comment: Your States seem like they could be better implemented as actual subclasses of a real `State` class.  That way you don't need any `if` or `case` statements to figure out what logic to run; Each subclass has an `Execute` method on it that has its own state specific logic.  If this sounds like something you are interested in, just let me know and I'll make a simple example for you.

Comment: This looks like an X/Y problem.  You're asking how to do X, but you should really ditch it and do Y.  Knowing the problem you're trying to solve here would help us suggest a good answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex and just parse the file:

```
private static List<string> GetUsedConstants(string path_to_file, string const_class)
{
    var text = File.ReadAllText(path_to_file);

    var rx = new Regex(const_class + @"\.\w+");

    return rx.Matches(text).Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible with reflection. Source code is not available through reflection; only meta-data.  And constants are replaced by their literal value after compiling, so even if you looked at the IL for the class, you wouldn't be able to tell if the constant was used or the literal string.

Parsing the source code is likely your best option.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. Yes, I thought so but because I'm kind of newbie about reflection, I wanted a confirmation.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, you seem to by trying to implement a "State Machine".  This doesn't directly answer your question, but it may help you solve your actual problem. States are implemented as actual subclasses of a real State class. That way you don't need any `if` or `case` statements to figure out which state's logic to run; Each subclass has an Execute method on it that has its own state specific logic. If this sounds like something you are interested in, just let me know and I'll make a simple example for you.

A very simple example of a state machine in a console application.  It switches between 2 states where one state counts from 1 to 5, and the 2nd state counts from 1 to 10.

```
using System;

namespace StateMachineExample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SimpleStateMachine sm = new SimpleStateMachine();
            sm.ChangeState(new State1(sm));
            sm.Run();
        }
    }

    class SimpleStateMachine
    {
        private State _currentState;
        public void Run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                _currentState.Execute();
            }
        }

        public void ChangeState(State newState)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Changing state to: {newState.GetType()}");
            _currentState = newState;
        }
    }

    abstract class State
    {
        public State(SimpleStateMachine sm)
        {
            StateMachine = sm;
        }

        protected SimpleStateMachine StateMachine { get; }

        public abstract void Execute();
    }

    class State1 : State
    {
        public State1(SimpleStateMachine sm) : base(sm) { }

        private int _num = 0;
        public override void Execute()
        {
            _num = _num + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(_num);

            if (_num > 10)
            {
                StateMachine.ChangeState(new State2(StateMachine));
            }
        }
    }

    class State2 : State
    {
        public State2(SimpleStateMachine sm) : base(sm) { }

        private int _num = 0;
        public override void Execute()
        {
            _num = _num + 1;
            Console.WriteLine(_num);

            if (_num > 5)
            {
                StateMachine.ChangeState(new State1(StateMachine));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your example. The idea is to create a state machine that is able to execute more than one behaviour at a time. In each behaviour there is the possibility to transition to a different state (that will be defined by the condition that first happens). Some of the behaviours are common to different states. The thing is that the states should be common for each single behaviour and the transitions will happen by defining the string of which state you want to be. Getting which state are used into a behaviour can give me the possibility to not trigger the wrong transition.